# Nginx returns a 404 for URLs like index.php/some/path

Tags: php, nginx

Nginx returns a 404 when I query for an URL with a "path info" appended after the script name, e.g. http://example.com/index.php/hello.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    root    @PROJECT_ROOT@/;
    index   index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:@PHP_FPM_SOCK@;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    }
}
```

I don't get why `\.php$` doesn't match that URL, and I've tried searching for similar problems but can't find anything useful.

Comment: The pattern `\.php$` is forcing nginx to match only URLs ending with `.php`. Why dont you a look on how popular frameworks arrange this setup like Symfony2? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Comment: @softius ah good point! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use

> location ~ ^.+.php {
>
> fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;

to match a .php in the uri split the parameters

Comment: That matches too broadly—on any character followed by "php".  You need backslashes before literal periods.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
location ~ \.php {
    # Split the path appropriately
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    # Work around annoying nginx "feature" (https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321)
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

    # Make sure the script exists.
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # Configure everything else.  This part may be different for you.
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```